# Entity Framework Core migrations through CI and CD in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core

I have created an Entity Framework Core project and it is working fine and I am able to generate migrations through Visual Studio.

But I want to generate SQL scripts through Azure Devops CI and deployment through CD. I am unable to do it.

By adding this command

```
dotnet ef migrations script --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\SampleEFCoreApplication\SampleEFCoreApplication.csproj -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\migrations\scripts.sql
```

This generates the entire SQL script. But next time, if I have to make any changes in my model, it again regenerates the entire SQL script. But I only want the changes to appear if I make any model changes. How can I do that ?

This is how my CI looks in Azure DevOps

[image]

Comment: There is a From To option that can be used to generate a script to migrate from a specific version to a specific version. It works like `dotnet ef migrations script 20180904195021_InitialCreate` Migrations may be identified by name or by ID and supplying it like this means that it will generate the script for the changes made after InitialCreate. I'll leave it up to you how you supply names you need but you might want to do this with powershell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the --idempotent option which will add code to the script so that only the appropriate migrations are applied to the database.  This effectively makes the sql script the equivalent of running `update-database` in the package manager console.