# Managing EF migrations in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: entity-framework, azure-devops, database-migration, azure-devops-pipelines

So our team has implemented a Windows self-hosted Azure DevOps testing pipeline. It was working well until we ran the backend tests for a branch that had a database migration. Although the tests passed as expect, this migration changed the agent's database. This resulted in every subsequent integration test run on the master branch to fail. Normally it would just 'down' the migration and it would be fine but here that migration doesn't exist since it was in a branch that hasn't been merged into master yet.

I've looked at a bunch of other posts about EF migrations and they all seem to talk about release pipelines and creating new migrations. All I want to do is have a step at the end of my pipeline that can update the database to whatever master's most recent migration is. However, I can't figure out how to do that since I don't have access to the NuGet Packet Manager Console. Does anyone know how I might go about updating the database to the appropriate migration? I am also pretty new to Azure DevOps pipelines so please let me know if this is misguided for whatever reason. Thank you for your help and please let me know if I can provide any more information.

If it is any help this is what we would use to update the database based on a given target migration in the NuGet Packet Manager Console:

```
Update-Database -projectName <projectName> -targetMigration <targetMigration> -configurationTypeName <configurationType> -connectionStringName <connectionString>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess the big problem I was running into is that my project is using EF 6 but most of the solutions online want you to use dotnet commands. To my knowledge (please let me know if I am mistaken) EF 6 can't use dotnet commands.

To get around this I used ef6.exe which allows you to make migrations via the command line. In the pipeline I just move that ef6.exe to where my project assembly file is and execute the migration. This worked for me but for anyone using EF Core, PatrickLu-MSFT's solution should work and be more straight forward.

Even though it was changed in EF 6.3 from migrate.exe it doesn't look like Microsoft has updated the docs for ef6.exe. To get an idea of what it is you can look at the out of date [migrate.exe documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe) and then the conversion table that was posted as a [github comment](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1740).

Conversion table from github comment linked above

[image: Conversion table:]

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could *mark it as a reply*.

Comment: Really sorry, I'm new to posting on stack overflow. Do you just mean mark this as the accepted answer, or should I have made this a comment on my original question?

Comment: @Andrew, He may write a part less, it should be mark it mark your reply as an answer. So, Chamberlain means you can accept your own answer, so it can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread :).

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [Update-Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#update-database) you should use `-Migration` paramater:

> The target migration. Migrations may be identified by name or by ID. The number 0 is a special case that means before the first migration and causes all migrations to be reverted. If no migration is specified, the command defaults to the last migration.

So it would be

```
Update-Database -Project <projectName> -Migration <targetMigration> -Connection <connectionString>
```

or using dotnet tool

```
dotnet ef database update <targetMigration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if totally get your point, you could take a look at this article--  [Entity Framework Core migrations through CI and CD in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027720/entity-framework-core-migrations-through-ci-and-cd-in-azure-devops)

> You can use the **--idempotent** option which will add code to the
> script so that only the appropriate migrations are applied to the
> database. This effectively makes the sql script the equivalent of
> running update-database in the package manager console.

With EntityFrameworkCore for example. DbContexts can be converted into databases, using the ‘dotnet ef migrations’ commands. As for how to use  dotnet ef command line to handle the process.

Please kindly refer this blog-- [EntityFrameworkCore, code-first migrations in Azure DevOps](https://medium.com/vx-company/entityframeworkcore-code-first-migrations-in-azure-devops-b5eb845fce18)  for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I looked into both of the articles and tried to implement their solutions but I'm having issues running the dotnet commands. It keeps saying I have circular dependencies with EF Core. I know these are both using EF Core whereas I am using EF 6. Do you know if this means I'm not able to use the dotnet commands at all?

Comment: @Andrew Sorry not so familiar with EF 6. If you are able to use same command line locally. It should also  qualify with Azure DevOps. Otherwise , you may not be able to use dotnet command for EF6. Alternatively, you could try to follow  *Krzysztof Madej*'s suggestion use  Update-Database command with  -Migration paramater:

Comment: Yeah it looks like I'm not able to use dotnet with EF 6. And I don't think their solution will work for me because the Update-Database also is only usable by EF Core (at least as far as I know).