# How are database changes managed/deployed in Azure DevOps when developing Blazor applications?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, azure-devops, blazor

When developing a Blazor application, I can generate a DbContext by adding a scaffolded item. Then, once I run Add-Migration and Update-Database, the database is generated. My question is, what is the recommended process to manage database changes in an Azure DevOps deployment scenario?

Is there something similar to the [Azure SQL database deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for SQL Server? Conceptually, I'm thinking running a task that executes Update-Database as a deployment task. Am I on the right track?

The previous way I did this was using user secrets and environment variables to manage the connection information and deploy the database manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something similar to the Azure SQL database deployment for SQL Server? Conceptually, I'm thinking running a task that executes Update-Database as a deployment task. Am I on the right track?

The `Azure SQL database deployment` task used SqlPackage.exe and Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet to deploy DACPACs or SQL Server scripts to Azure SQL server. For SQL server, the similar tick is [SQL Server database deploy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md).

You are on the right track by using Entity Framework Core (EF Core) to manage your database schema. Instead of `Update-Database`, you can use `dotnet ef migrations script  --idempotent` which is equal, please check the similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027720/entity-framework-core-migrations-through-ci-and-cd-in-azure-devops) for your reference.